# Data type to hold mdb file

Tags: vb.net

Because of machinery requirements I need to store `mdb` files in a `SQL Server` database and retrieve them from a workstation.  I do not need to manipulate the data at all, simply copy and paste from the server to the computer.  I am using `varbinary` to store them in the database.

What data type in `.NET` can hold a raw file like an `mdb`?

Comment: I ultimately decided that overall performance would be better if the data was stored using simple data types and the `mdb` file was generated on the user end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array of byte:

```
Dim mdb As Byte()
```

This is probably your best bet, since a lot of functionality related to working with binary files in .NET is based off `Byte()`. Examples:

- [BinaryReader.ReadBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes.aspx)
- [BinaryWriter.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx149a0k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)